# MongoDB Aggregation - $project and $match stages not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that has the `createdAt` field. I want to get the documents greater than 1st day of last month. I created an aggregation query and added the date with 1st day of last month to each document. However, when I use `$match` to filter out the documents, I get empty documents, though there is some data in the DB.

This is the query:

```
db.user_activity_trackings.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        "firstDayOfLastMonth": {
            "$dateFromParts": {
                "year": { "$year": { "$dateAdd": { "startDate": "$$NOW", "unit": "month", "amount": -1 } } },
                "month": { "$month": { "$dateAdd": { "startDate": "$$NOW", "unit": "month", "amount": -1 } } },
                "day": 1
            }
        },
        "createdAt": 1,
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        "createdAt": { $gte: "$firstDayOfLastMonth" }
    }
}])
```

Comment: please add some sample input and your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter the document by comparing both fields in the document, you require to use the [`$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#behavior) operator.

> `$expr` can build query expressions that compare fields from the same document in a `$match` stage.

```
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $gte: [
        "$createdAt",
        "$firstDayOfLastMonth"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JoxyotiKTH8)